# Using flip toggle switch i my not getting alert message when toogle is "off" or "on"

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Using flip toggle switch i my not getting alert message when toogle is "off" or "on"
in jquery mobile plz help me out

in html5

```
<select name="toggleswitch1" id="toggleswitch1" data-theme="" data-role="slider">
  <option value="off">Off</option>
  <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

in script

```
 $(document).bind("pageinit", function () {    
   $("#toggleswitch1").unbind('change').bind('change', function() {
     if ($("#toggleswitch1").val('off').slider('refresh')) {
       alert("off");
     }
     else {
       alert("on");
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: `if($(this).val() == 'on'` and `if($(this).val() == 'off'`. Why are you using refresh here? It's in the wrong place.

Comment: I faced similar issues when doing off(change).on(change) the select did not update, so I had to use .change(function{});

Comment: @Omar you are fast man :)

Comment: @abdu I work out every morning ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/39DEK/

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).off('slidestop',"#toggleswitch1").on('slidestop', "#toggleswitch1" ,function() {      
        if ($("#toggleswitch1 option:selected").val() == 'off')  {
            alert("off");
        } else {
            alert("on");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: if we have to change the page if toggle is "ON" it goes to another html page suppose one.html how we can do

Comment: You want to change page when slider is changed to on?